# Magento2 Add simple product as a qty instead a seperate product when group product is used

Tags: magento2, grouped-products

Has anyone tried something like when we have a group product with 2 SKUs (Prod A & Prod B)

> If I add this grp product to the cart it will be added as Prod A & Prod B (normal behavoiur)

> Now, when I individually add Prod A to add to cart then instead of adding this Prod A as a seperate product in cart just increase the Qty

Please advice this is important for me

Comment: It is not clear what exactly you want done since most of the question is just quoted text, I think you want to make it so that Product A is not added as a different product but rather get added into existing product A in the cart.

Comment: Yes @VivekKumar correct that is the need that ProductA should be added into existing product of group product & not as a seperate product

Answer (score 0):

I do not have an empty instance with me so most of what I am saying is off the top of my head, but I think when you add a grouped product even if it is showing up as two different products it has parent's product id in the quote item. So in the `representProduct()` function it is failing the first check i.e

```
if (!$product || $itemProduct->getId() != $product->getId()) {
            return false;
        }
```

If it is so you would have to override the `representProduct()` function as well as the function which merges products based on `representProduct()` function's return function (most probably `\Magento\Quote\Model\Quote::getItemByProduct`).

Answer (score 0):

you can add your own logic in `representProduct` method based on this method magento add items  in separate line or increase QTY

you can pluginize representProduct method located in
`Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item`

your `[Vendor]/[Module]/etc/di.xml` looks like below

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd" >
    <type name='Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item'>
        <plugin name='beforeDispatch' type='[Vendor]\[Module]\Plugin\Model\Quote\ItemPlugin' sortOrder='99'/>
    </type>    
</config>
```

and your `[Vendor]\[Module]\Plugin\Model\Quote\ItemPlugin.php` looks like below

```
<?php

namespace [Vendor]\[Module]\Plugin\Model\Quote;
class ItemPlugin 
{
    
    public function afterRepresentProduct(\Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item $subject, $result)
    {
        if ($yourCondition) { 
             $result = false;
        }
        return $result;
    }
}
```

Comment: How do I get current product details in after?

Comment: $subject->getProduct(), I think

Comment: I tried but not working